# In unit testing, how to test a function having object parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

When unit testing, do you have to send a full realistic object parameter? 
Or you just send an object parameter containing properties that are needed in the function?

For Example, here is a sample function that needs unit test:

```
    function ChangeName(person) {
      if (person !== null) {
        let {firstName} = person.firstName;
        firstName = firstName + '_firstName';
        person.firstName = firstName;
        return person;
      }
      return person;
    }
```

Here is a sample test that sends a full object:

```
    expect(
      ChangeName(
        {
          firstName: 'Juan', 
          lastName: 'dela Cruz', 
          age: 22, 
          gender: 'Male', 
          aboutMe: 'About_Me', 
          schools:[
            {id: 1, name: 'School Name 1'},
            {id: 1, name: 'School Name 1'},
            {id: 1, name: 'School Name 1'},
            {id: 1, name: 'School Name 1'}
          ]
        }
      )
    ).toEqual(
      {
        firstName: 'Juan_firstName', 
        lastName: 'dela Cruz', 
        age: 22, 
        gender: 'Male', 
        aboutMe: 'About_Me', 
        schools:[
          {id: 1, name: 'School Name 1'},
          {id: 1, name: 'School Name 1'},
          {id: 1, name: 'School Name 1'},
          {id: 1, name: 'School Name 1'}
        ]
      }
    );
```

Here is a sample test sends an object that has properties only needed in the function (includes the lastName, just for sample) :

```
    expect(
      ChangeName(
        {
          firstName: 'Juan', 
          lastName: 'dela Cruz', 
        }
      )
    ).toEqual(
      {
        firstName: 'Juan_firstName', 
        lastName: 'dela Cruz', 
      }
    );
```

Comment: You can mock objects using mocking frameworks such as Sinon.js

Answer (score 1):

I provide the code I test with only what is needed.

In your case this would mean :

```
expect(changeName({ 
    firstName: 'Juan',
    lastName: 'dela Cruz'
}).toEqual({ 
    firstName: 'Juan_firstName',
    lastName: 'dela Cruz'
});
```

Why ?

- Less work when refactoring the person object
- Tests are more readable, you only have what is concerned by the test
- With duck typing and/or functional programming you can reuse this function on other objects (pets…)
- `lastName` (or any other name) explicits that nothing else should change

This would probably change in case you use typing (flow, typescript).

---

Also I noticed a few mistakes which may bother you:

```
let { firstName } = person;
```

You do not have to repeat firstName

```
const newPerson = {
    ...person,
    firstName: firstName + '_firstName'
}
return newPerson;
```

This way you do not mutate the original person object which can be harmful in React.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the guarantees you want your test to provide.

In your example, if the only thing you want to check is "the `firstName` property is updated as expected", `{ firstName: 'Juan' }` is the right level of complexity for the argument passed to the `changeName` function.

However, if the guarantees your test need to provide is actually "the `firstName` property is updated as expected, *and nothing else should be changed*", it becomes important to have a complete object, representative of the kind of data the function is expected to handle.

The latter might be harder to read, if implemented as shown in your test example. That can be mitigated by putting the object creation in an utility function, in which case it can be as readable as the much simpler example.

```
// buildPerson() creates a new, complete 'person' object when called,
// and overrides its properties with the provided ones
expect(
  changeName(buildPerson({ firstName: 'Juan' }))
).toEqual(
  buildPerson({ firstName: 'Juan_firstName' })
);
```